# Xamarin Forms Get Device Ip address

Tags: xamarin.forms, ip

I'm working with a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform app. Now, I need to obtain the device home Ip (I mean the static one).  Which is the simplest way to get the IPv4 address of the device in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Dns.GetHostAddresses` which is under `using System.Net`

**Call this function**

```cs
var ip = GetLocalAddress();
```

**GetLocalAddress:**

```cs
private string GetLocalAddress()
{
    var IpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault();

    if (IpAddress != null)
        return IpAddress.ToString();

    return "Could not locate IP Address";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DependencyService to get Ip address, then following code is Android project. For other Platform, you can take a look:

```
class IPAddressManager : IIPAddressManager
{
    public string GetIPAddress()
    {
        IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        if (addresses?[0] != null)
        {
            return addresses[0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/how-to-easily-get-device-ip-address-in-xamarin-forms-using-dependencyservice/