# Do we have any specific method in Xamarin iOS to read the all the connected IP Address from iPhone version 14+?

Tags: ios, xamarin

Hi I am trying to read all the connected IP Address from the iPhone using NetworkInterface as well tried with Dns.GetHostEntryAsync. Both are works fine with the iPhone 7 which has the iOS version is 15.6.2. Actually my app has to connect with the local Wi-Fi network device. So when app launch itself we are getting the local network access from the user. Even if we give permission also iPhone XR with the version 16.0.3 doesn't not return the local network connected device ip address. If we turn on the Aeroplan Mode then iPhone XR returns the connected local wi-fi device ip.

Do we need to give any other permission from iOS side or how do we get the local wi-fi device ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313149/xamarin-forms-get-device-ip-address) which might help you get device ip address.
Also, the way of **DependencyService** could be used to make it. You may refer to this [article](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/05/16/how-to-easily-get-device-ip-address-in-xamarin-forms-using-dependencyservice/)

Comment: Shen - I have tried both the options already. But the problem is those API's doesn't return the iPhone connected local network wi-fi device which doesn't have the internet. But same API returns those local network wi-fi device IP address in iPhone 7. Problem is iPhone XR and other latest iPhone devices not returning those IP Addresses.

Comment: Well could you please provide some related code that work well on your iPhone 7?

Comment: Please find the code i am using to get all the connected ip address
public static List<IPAddress> GetLocalIPAddressList()
{
List<IPAddress> list = new List<IPAddress>();
IPAddress[] addressList = Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(Dns.GetHostName()).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
.AddressList;
foreach (IPAddress iPAddress in addressList)
{
if (iPAddress.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
list.Add(iPAddress);
}
}
return list;
}

Comment: What did it return or just throw an exception when you use iphone xr ? It seems work well on a simulator.

Comment: It's not throw any exception but not return the locally connected IP address

Comment: Do you want to get the router ip address? Take a look if this article could help [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57197f3d-53bf-4509-a0d6-43b5eceb73d9/how-can-we-capture-the-ip-address-of-the-router-the-smartphone-is-connected-to-on-wifi-?forum=xamarinforms)